# CARES-related withdrawal: eligible plan vs. opt-in

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, retirement-plan, withdrawal

It seems a qualified individual with an eligible retirement plan can apply CARES act provisions with regard to withdrawals/distributions received during calendar year 2020, whether or not the plan administrator chooses to opt-in.

Does this entail that, even though the administrator applies 10% tax penalty plus (at least) 20% tax, the individual can treat a distribution made for another reason as a COVID-19 distribution (no 10% tax penalty, taxation spread over 3 years) and claim overdue taxes back?

Are there any guidelines to determine whether a certain plan is eligible? My specific case is an optional retirement plan (ORP), which I believe is regulated by §401(a), and for which employment termination constitutes a "distributable event".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the administrator of a qualified plan (or IRA) does not 'apply' any tax, including the 10% 'penalty' for early distribution. The adminstrator does specify codes on the 1099-R for the distribution(s) such as:

```
 1—Early distribution, no known exception (...)
 2—Early distribution, exception applies (...)
```

Note the "known". Exceptions to 72(t) exist (even before COVID) that the administrator does not or may not know about. *You* are the one responsible for designating, on 5329, what exception if any applies, and either computing the resulting extra tax or not. I presume the 2020 instructions, when issued, will allocate a code for CARES/COVID. (And there will probably be a form, or at least a checkbox or suchlike, for the 3-year spreading.)

And the 20% *withholding* on eligible rollover distributions isn't tax either, only withholding -- i.e. an estimate, and a crude one compared to wage withholding, which *most* of the time is *close* to correct. When you prepare your return next spring, your actual tax attributable to this item may be more *or* less.

To your actual question, **no the adminstrator needn't agree** this is COVID-related. See [notice 2020-50 in IRB 2020-28](https://www.irs.gov/irb/2020-28_IRB#NOT-2020-50) in "Section 1" at "C. Definition of coranavirus-related distribution":

> In general, a qualified individual is permitted to designate a distribution described in the preceding paragraph as a coronavirus-related distribution. This designation is permitted to be made with respect to any distribution to a qualified individual that would meet the requirements of a coronavirus-related distribution without regard to whether the plan treated the distribution as a coronavirus-related distribution. Thus, periodic payments and distributions that would have been required minimum distributions but for section 2203 of the CARES Act, received by a qualified individual from an eligible retirement plan on or after January 1, 2020, and before December 31, 2020, are permitted to be treated as coronavirus-related distributions and, therefore, permitted to be included in income ratably over 3 years. Similarly, any distribution received by a qualified individual as a beneficiary can be treated as a coronavirus-related distribution. In addition, ....

> As explained in section 2.C of this notice, an employer retirement plan also is permitted, but not required, to treat a plan distribution meeting the conditions described in this section 1.C as a coronavirus-related distribution. It is possible that a qualified individual’s designation of a coronavirus-related distribution may be different from the employer retirement plan’s treatment of the distribution. This different treatment could occur, for example, if a qualified individual has more than one plan distribution that meets the requirements of a coronavirus-related distribution, but one of those distributions occurs before the effective date of the plan amendment providing for coronavirus-related distributions. The different treatment could also occur, for example, if a qualified individual has distributions from more than one eligible retirement plan, and the aggregate amount of those distributions exceeds $100,000.

As to whether the plan you're in is 'eligible', that is covered in "Background" "A. Distributions" where the list includes, stated very briefly "a qualified plan under § 401(a)". I've never heard of "Optional Retirement Plan" as a specific, defined thing and it certainly doesn't appear in any IRS publications I've read or the law I've looked at. I suggest checking your paperwork -- under ERISA you should have received at the very least a Summary Plan Description every year, and usually quite a few other required disclosures -- to try to determine if this specifically is a 401a qualified plan (or any of the others listed in the notice) and if necessary try to compare to [the law](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/401) (which is quite convoluted and often arcane).